# Why does my fetch method not return JSON?

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, fetch

I have an ASP.NET Core project with React as the framework.

I use the following model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace drivingSchoolManagement.Models
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Customers
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string First_name { get; set; }
        public string Last_name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool Is_active { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the following Controller:

```
using drivingSchoolManagement.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace drivingSchoolManagement.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public class CustomersController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<CustomersController> _logger;
        private readonly DatabaseConnection _dbConnection;

        public CustomersController(ILogger<CustomersController> logger, DatabaseConnection dbConnection)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _dbConnection = dbConnection;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Get()
        {
            return new JsonResult(_dbConnection.GetAllCustomers());
        }

    }
}
```

In my React component Customers.js I want to output the data I get, for this I wrote the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Customers extends Component {
    static displayName = Customers.name;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { customers: [] };

        this.getCustomers();
    }

    async getCustomers() {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('customers', {
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                },
            });
            console.log(response);
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(response.statusText);
            }
            const data = await response.json();
            this.setState({ customers: data });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }


    render() {
        const customers = this.state.customers.map(customer => {
            return (
                <div key={customer.id}>
                    <p>ID: {customer.id}</p>
                    <p>First name: {customer.first_name}</p>
                    <p>Last name: {customer.last_name}</p>
                    <p>Address: {customer.address}</p>
                    <p>Zip: {customer.zip}</p>
                    <p>Phone: {customer.phone}</p>
                    <p>Email: {customer.email}</p>
                    <p>Is active: {customer.is_active ? 'Yes' : 'No'}</p>
                </div>
            );
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Customers</h1>
                {customers}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Also in my DatabaseConnection.cs I have folling:

```
 public List<Customers> GetAllCustomers()
        {
            List<Customers> customers = new List<Customers>();

            using (NpgsqlConnection connection = OpenConnection())
            {
                string query = "SELECT * FROM customers";
                NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(query, connection);

                using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        customers.Add(new Customers
                        {
                            Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                            First_name = reader.GetString(1),
                            Last_name = reader.GetString(2),
                            Address = reader.GetString(3),
                            Zip = reader.GetString(4),
                            Phone = reader.GetString(5),
                            Email = reader.GetString(6),
                            Is_active = reader.GetBoolean(7)
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            return customers;
        }
```

The Status is 404 not found, also the type is html.
Maybe you overlook what I did wrong.

Comment: What do you see when you do console.log(response); ?

Comment: Do you perhaps need to provide the full url to your api: `await fetch('customers')` is not a complete url.

Comment: Check the network tab. Is the URL of the network request correct? I doubt it's not, so instead of `'customers'`, use `'/customers'` as URL. You could've also set a breakpoint in the Action and see if it's hit or not...

Comment: @HenryDev this is the output: Response { type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:44417/customers", redirected: false, status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers(12), body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }

Comment: @Sternisic 1) Put a breakpoint in the CustomersController constructor. 2) After running, try hitting the endpoint manually, open a tab and go to the URL and slowly debug. Also, check the Output Window (if you are using Visual Studio) for any Exceptions

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the forward slash like this?

```
const response = await fetch('/customers', {
```

Also,
How about adding this in your controller to make your endpoint available:

```
[Route("customer")]
[ApiController]
public class CustomerController : ControllerBase
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: I tried, but still the same.

Comment: @Sternisic I just updated my answer to make your endpoint available.

Comment: unfortunately did not work either

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the `fetch('customers')` part.
It should be `fetch('/customers')` (starting with a slash).

I don't know why [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) behaves like this (so, differently with/without slash), but let me explain the 'problem'.

The anatomy of a URL is like this:
[image]

Focus on the **domain** and **path**, forget the others for now.

- `fetch('/customers')`
  When you use a URL starting with a slash `/`, it replaces the entire **path** part from the URL.
  So: [www.example.com/path/to/myfile](http://www.example.com/path/to/myfile) -> [www.example.com/customers](http://www.example.com/customers)
- `fetch('customers')`
  When you use a URL that doesn't start with a slash `/`, it somehow replaces only the last part of the **path** (in case it contains multiple parts).
  So: [www.example.com/path/to/myfile](http://www.example.com/path/to/myfile) -> [www.example.com/path/to/customers](http://www.example.com/path/to/customers)

  You wouldn't notice this kind of behaviour in case the **path** contained only 1 part, as the resulting URL would be the same in both cases (either with or without `/`).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I didn't work. It has to be something else, I guess something small